# How to create auto click in every 5 second

Tags: android

I want to click a button automatically every 5 seconds. Here is my code. This runs something after 5 seconds but how can I click the button *every* 5 seconds automatically?

```java
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //my Activity should add here
    }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Click what? A button?

Comment: yeah. it's a button.

Comment: `button.performClick();`, `button.postDelayed(this, 5000);`. You don't even need that `Handler`. You can call the first `postDelayed()` on the `button`.

Comment: i didn't get it.

Comment: Those lines to where your `//my Activity should add here` comment is.

Comment: its not working...

Comment: That's not an adequate problem description. If you need further assistance,  [edit] your question to provide a [mcve], and to describe exactly how and where it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this following:

```
private Handler callItSelfHandler;
private Runnable callItSelfrunnable;

    public void callItself()
    {
        callItSelfHandler = new Handler();
        callItSelfHandler.postDelayed(callItSelfrunnable = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                button.performClick();  //here your button will be called automatically
                Log.e("callItself_", "callItself_>>>");
                callItSelfHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
```

To remove can use like this:

```
callItSelfHandler.removeCallbacks(callItSelfrunnable);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Runnable clickAction = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        button.performClick();
        button.postDelayed(this, 5000);
    }
};

// To start it
button.postDelayed(clickAction, 5000);

// To stop
button.removeCallbacks(clickAction);
```